# 清淡 (qing dan) usage: any food, or from a diet?

Tags: meaning

I ate with a Chinese who mentioned the soup was `清淡 (qing dan)`: clear, and bland. On Google all I found were acupuncture and "macrobiotic diet" websites.

Is `清淡 (qing dan)` an adjective commonly applied to food that is simple and light, or is it reserved for food from a special diet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's written as 清淡 and used in different contexts.

1. For light colors, smells
2. For light (non-greasy, non-oily) food
3. Business running slow or slacking
4. In arts for a simple style

Answer (score 3):

When referring to food, "清淡" means *"low-salt, low-fat, less sugar, less meat, low cholesterol, non-alcoholic and not spicy"*.

In a wide sense,it does mean light and simple food, no fried-no barbecue-less edible oil; In a narrow sense, it is related to the Chinese culture which is very intriguing and complex to explain.

Answer (score 1):

These words are related to the Chinese culture.

Tea have been thought of `qing dan`, but coffee is reverse. Vegetable been thought of `qing dan`, but meat is not.

In traditional culture all these stuff like eat vegetables, drink tea, no sexual life, no smoke and no wine are be seen as `Qing`.

Before, some people thought it can make themself live long.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, it refers to food as low-salt, low-fat, less sugar, less meat, low cholesterol, non-alcoholic and not spicy. Seldom for other usage, do not make things complicated.